# Amount of distance to travel when a key is pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

In code below, I want to manage the amount of distance to travel when a left arrow key is pressed depending upon if it's half way down or not.
The object moves all the way to left on very first press instead of movement to be divided in 3 or 4 parts depending on the above mentioned condition, where am I doing it wrong?

```
var diff = Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x - r.renderer.bounds.min.x);
print("diff" + diff);
var lessdistancetotravel = diff/4;
var moredistancetotravel = diff/3;

if(this.transform.position.x > half)
{
    print ("greater than half while moving left");  
    print("currentpos"  + this.transform.position.x); //gives 0.6
    print("moredistance " + moredistancetotravel);//gives 0.69
    this.transform.position = new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x - moredistancetotravel, 
                                           this.transform.position.y,
                                           this.transform.position.z);
    print("updated" + (this.transform.position.x - moredistancetotravel)); //gives -0.78,How come?
}
```

Comment: Are you using an analog input device?  There is no such thing as "half way down" on a standard keyboard, it's either down or not down, there is no half.  You should also include more of code, we have no idea what `this` or `half` are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't check how far down a key is pressed, as [Jerdak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222233/jerdak) mentioned in the comments. I would then just measure how long a key has been pressed. You can start counting how long the key has been down and stop counting once it is released. Then you can use that time to determine how far your object can travel.

How to count the time the key has been pressed:

```
float count = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
     if(Input.GetKey("a"))
         count += Time.deltaTime;

     else if(Input.GetKeyUp("a"))
         count = 0.0f;
}
```

Code resets count back to 0 once you release the key.

Comment: Oh, By half way down, I meant if the moving car is half way across the width of the road :)